# Confirmar exclusão no Laravel 5.4

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

eu tenho o form abaixo, no qual um botão exclui o registro da linha atual.

```
<form  class="form-inline" method="POST" action="/servidores/{{ $serve->id }}">
        {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"'>Excluir</button>
</form>
```

Ele funciona, mas não confirma a exclusão; deleta onclick. 
É possível adicionar a confirmação com os recursos do laravel?

Answer (score 1):

Use o `confirm` do Javascript colocando ele em `onsubmit` do seu formulário para isso.

Veja:

```
<form  class="form-inline" method="POST" action="/servidores/{{ $serve->id }}" onsubmit="confirm('Tem certeza que deseja excluir?')">
        {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"'>Excluir</button>
</form>
```

Você ainda pode fazer de forma mais sofisticada, separando a lógica num arquivo Javascript.

Veja um exemplo:

```
$('#formulario').on('submit', function () {

     var confirmado = confirm('Deseja deletar esses dados?');

     if (! confirmado) return false;
});
```

Nesse último exemplo, você precisaria colocar o atributo `id` com o valor `formulário` no seu `form`.

Se for usar javascript puro, basta fazer assim:

```
document.querySelector('#formulario').addEventListener('submit', function () {
      // mesmo código anterior
});
```